# Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. Any ideas?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have honestly trawled through the existing questions for the answer, but this one is a total mystery.

Firebase.js

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Auth } from "../contexts/AuthContext";

export const FirebaseLogout = async () => {
  const { state: auth, dispatch } = useContext(Auth);
  const logout = await firebase
    .auth()
    .signOut()
    .then(
      dispatch({
        type: "LOGOUT",
      })
    )
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      return err;
    });
  return;
};
```

MyPage.js

```
import { FirebaseLogout } from "../../../firebase/Firebase";
```

> ```
> ...Stateless functional component with other non-relevant code between...
> ```

```
<Button onClick={() => FirebaseLogout()} type='primary'>
  {auth.user.uid ? "Logout" : "Sign up"}
</Button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FirebaseLogout is an action or an handler and hence can't use the `useContext` hook. The solution is to either make it into a custok hook or pass in the context value as argument

```
export const FirebaseLogout = async () => {

  const logout = await firebase
    .auth()
    .signOut()
    .then(
      dispatch({
        type: "LOGOUT",
      })
    )
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      return err;
    });
  return;
};
```

MyPage.js

```
const contextValue = useContext(Auth);


  <Button onClick={() => FirebaseLogout(contextValue)} type='primary'>
     {auth.user.uid ? "Logout" : "Sign up"}
   </Button>
```

Comment: also one more thing... i don't see any reason to use async, await, the logout variable and the return at the end... as they don't seem to do anything.

Comment: You got it. Thanks. @d3bgger Doesn't the async need to be there since firebase calls take time from the main thread?

Comment: firebase call returns a promise, it isn't blocking. You are using then () to do something when the promise resolves. The await  would be useful if you wanted to continue doing something, after firebase call is completed... but you are not.

Comment: @d3bgger got it, that's really helpful, thank you both